# Flutter file is written but nowhere to be found

Tags: flutter, path, imagepicker

See the following code:

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Directory? directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
String id = "z8PANL7qgbg9XJOQQZM2V9RnP5nESNvi";
try {
    String fullPathName = directory.path + '/' + id + '.jpg';
    file = File(fullPathName).writeAsBytes(data);
    print("success $fullPathName");
  }
```

I get the following output:

```
success /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/z8PANL7qgbg9XJOQQZM2V9RnP5nESNvi.jpg
```

It seems that the file is successfully written but then when I try to see the file (an image), with ImagePicker, it is impossible to find it anywhere.

NB: I use Android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this way**

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ImD;
File file;

photoAdress() async {
final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final path= directory .path;
ImD.Image photo= ImD.decodeImage(dosya.readAsBytesSync());
var formed= File("$path/img_$gonderiID.jpg")..writeAsBytesSync(ImD.encodeJpg(photo, quality: 90));
setState(() {
  file= formed;
});
```

}

Comment: That is nice of you but I want to understand why it is not working before jumping to another way